# webgl skybox textures artifacts on cube edges

Tags: textures, webgl, skybox

I am working on a project in webgl (I cannot use three.js or other lib) and when I render skybox it looks like this:

[image: skybox issue]

as you can see, on the edges of the cube there are some lines, so it can be said where skybox textures meet. **Note that the same textures work well with three.js library** So it has to be something wrong with my drawing code.

My cube .obj:

```
v 500 500 500
v 500 500 -500
v 500 -500 500
v 500 -500 -500
v -500 500 -500
v -500 500 500
v -500 -500 -500
v -500 -500 500
vt 0 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 0
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
f 1/1/1 3/2/2 2/3/3
f 3/4/4 4/5/5 2/6/6
f 5/7/7 7/8/8 6/9/9
f 7/10/10 8/11/11 6/12/12
f 5/13/13 6/14/14 2/15/15
f 6/16/16 1/17/17 2/18/18
f 8/19/19 7/20/20 3/21/21
f 7/22/22 4/23/23 3/24/24
f 6/25/25 8/26/26 1/27/27
f 8/28/28 3/29/29 1/30/30
f 2/31/31 4/32/32 5/33/33
f 4/34/34 7/35/35 5/36/36
```

My drawing code:

```
    for(var i=0, len=TexturesArray.length; i<len; i++) {
        _gl.bindTexture(_gl.TEXTURE_2D, TexturesArray[i].glTex); 
        _gl.drawElements(_gl.TRIANGLES, (Object.offset ? Object.offset : Object.Triangles.length), _gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, i*6*2);   
    }
```

Texture loads:

```
this.loadTexture = function(Img, opts){  
        var TempTex = _gl.createTexture();  
        _gl.bindTexture(_gl.TEXTURE_2D, TempTex);    

        //_gl.pixelStorei(_gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);  

        _gl.texImage2D(_gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, _gl.RGBA, _gl.RGBA, _gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, Img);    

        _gl.texParameteri(_gl.TEXTURE_2D, _gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, _gl.LINEAR);
        _gl.texParameteri(_gl.TEXTURE_2D, _gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, _gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        _gl.generateMipmap(_gl.TEXTURE_2D);   

        _gl.bindTexture(_gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);  
        return TempTex;  
    };
```

Does anybody know what can be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to add:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

It should help if you don't use Cube Maps.

Comment: Why it won't work in Cube Maps?I'm using a BoxGeometry with Three.js and has the same probem.My question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738750/how-can-i-remove-white-line-or-alias-when-making-a-skybox-in-three-js